# Typo3 enabling default Link Browser

Tags: ckeditor, typo3, rte

I have an alternative Link Browser, but I dont know why (maybe because an extension?) how do I deactivate it or enable the default one?
[image: picture of the link browser I have]

I couldn't find someone that also has this Link window, so maybe if anyone ever had this one and knows where it's coming from.

Comment: Which version of TYPO3 are you using?

Comment: Im using version 11.5.24 @JulianHofmann

Comment: The wizard looks like the normal CKeditor4-wizard (https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/link). But I have no idea, why you do not get  TYPO3's wizard. Any extension, which is overriding RTE stuff?

Comment: I removed every extension to test it, but it didn't change anything, is there a way to see what is overriding the link browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have created and registered a custom rte.yaml for your extension, you have to import the plugins.yaml from the core to get the expected link browser.

It should look like this:

```
imports:
  - { resource: "EXT:rte_ckeditor/Configuration/RTE/Editor/Plugins.yaml" }
```